# Can get only Mail Message body?

Tags: c#, .net, email

I use free .net library to read email and I release: If I want to view body message, all free .net email library download body message and attachments. If attachments have a big size, I wait for a long time. Example: I use AE.NET.Mail to read the lastest email:

```
        var dt = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToLongTimeString());
        // Connect to the IMAP server. The 'true' parameter specifies to use SSL
        // which is important (for Gmail at least)
        var ic = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", "yourEmail", "yourPassword",
                        ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true);
        // Select a mailbox. Case-insensitive
        var mailCount = ic.GetMessageCount();
        ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
        var message = ic.GetMessage(mailCount - 1);
        var body = message.Body;
        Console.WriteLine(body);
        ic.Disconnect();
        ic.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - dt).TotalSeconds);
```

result: 478,6s with attachment size 23mb.
How can I do if I want to view only body message with fastest speed?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you link please follow it and try another open source mail library It helps you to consume less time . [TRY THIS](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/reading-mails-using-imap-and-mailsystem-net/) Then put the code as shown below

```
  MailRepository rep = new MailRepository("imap.gmail.com", 993, true, @"username", "password");

    foreach (ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message email in rep.GetUnreadMails("Inbox"))
    {

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<p>{0}: {1}</p><p>{2}</p>", email.From, email.Subject, email.BodyHtml.Text));


    }
```

Comment: MailSystem.NET is the old library. I tested it and I can't believe it's very slow.